# Spring `@Scheduled` doesn't start until first HTTP hit?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-scheduled

I defined a controller with two methods:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "* * * * * *")
private void heartBeat() {
    logger.info("here");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/now", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getDate() {
    return Instant.now().toString();
}
```

My config looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Config extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Config.class);
    }
```

When I first startup the app, nothing happens.

Then, as soon as I hit `curl http://localhost/now`, the `heartBeat()` method starts executing periodically.

Why doesn't it start right away?

Comment: did you add `@EnableScheduling`?

Comment: yes in my Config, please see update

Comment: write scheduler code in new class with @Component annotation and try.

Comment: `@Component` was already there, but I was missing `@ComponentScan`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was just missing a `@ComponentScan` annotation.

Answer (score -1):

Change the `@Scheduled(cron = "* * * * * *")` to 
`@Scheduled(fixedRate = "* * * * * *")`. 
This will trigger the scheduled method once the application starts.